# How to append large data in HTML table through javascript without crashing the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, performance, html-table

We have a javascript function to load data from JSON to HTML table, but the amount of data is very large as it have 99 columns in it with more than 10000 rows.
When we run this function, the browser crashes and goes blank.

We tried couple of javascript plugins like clusterize, but still the issue persists.
We also tried pagination and still the same issue of browser crashing.

```
function getdata_table(data){
var count=0;
var head = "<tr><th>col_head1</th>........<th>col_head99</th><tr>"
$("#table").append(head);
$.each(data,function(){
var entry = "<td>"+data[count].col1+"</td><td>"+data[count].col2+"</td>.....<td>"+data[count].col99+"</td>"
var line = "<tr>"+ entry +"</tr>";
$("#table").append(line);
count =count+1;
});
}
```

We want to present the whole data in tabular format.

Comment: why on Earth would you want to show more than 10,000 rows in one page? Limit it to a sensible amount (20-30, 100 absolute max) and use pagination

Comment: Will the user be able to look at 10,000 rows and find what they want? I recommend that you look at implementing a paging scheme where you bring back chunks of data as they scroll, or give the user the ability to enter filter criteria that limits the data.

Comment: From a performance standpoint though, appending one row at a time is creating multiple touch points on the DOM, which cause the page to re-evaluate and redraw.  Building up an array, or string, containing all the html you want to append and appending just once, reduces this work load.

Comment: I tried using pagination to limit it to 20 per page, but still due to the append function, it's failing.

Comment: If you are paging 20 at a time, you do not need to append 10,000.  You need to append a smaller amount, and fetch more when necessary

Comment: @Taplar can you please help me with how I can implement that?

Comment: There is a jquery plugin called datatable for displaying data in tabular format. It has server-side processing capabilities. You can check it [here](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html). The example is of PHP, but you can implement it using any other backend language of your choice.